# Google Sheets REGEXREPLACE to keep one of repeated strings if in the middle but remove them if at the beginning or the end

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets

I have a string that may have repeated ", " (a comma and a space) in the middle, or at the beginning, or at the end.

for example, to clean `", , a, , c, d, "`

I use REGEXREPLACE twice:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(", , a, , c, d, ","(, )+",", "),"^(, )|(, )$","")
```

Result: `"a, c, d"`

Is it possible to do it in just one REGEXREPLACE?

Comment: Please provide at lease one expected input/output to your question

Comment: It is not possible because RE2 does not support conditional replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks

Comment: It turns out you can achieve what you need with mere capturing and backreferences.

Answer (score 2):

use the regex

```
^[, ]+(?=[a-z])|[, ]+$|[, ]+(?=, )
```

http://regexr.com/3ct8r

or

```
^[, ]+(?=[a-zA-Z])|[, ]+$|[, ]+(?=, )
```

for lower and upper case support, and replace with nothingness

---

I have just read the doc syntax of RE2 at:

https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html

```
Single characters:
[xyz]   character class

Composites:
x|y x or y (prefer x)

Repetitions:
x+  one or more x, prefer more

Grouping:
(re)    numbered capturing group
(?:re)  non-capturing group

Empty strings:
^   at beginning of text or line (m=true)
$   at end of text (like \z not \Z) or line (m=true)
```

then, the regex

```
^[, ]+|[, ]+$|(?:, )+(, [a-zA-Z])
```

and replacement with "capturing group" 1, should do the trick.

Comment: RE2 does not support lookaheads.

Comment: Yes, "smart" capturing works. Still, you can shorten the solution to `=REGEXREPLACE(A11,"^[, ]+|[, ]+$|(, )+","$1")`

Comment: @siete.sh  and Wiktor Stribiżew well done! Just one more question: what's the difference between `(, )` and `[, ]` ? I use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(, )+|(, )+$|(, )+","$3")`

Comment: Oh, I got it.  you use`[, ]` to remove any comma `,` or space `␣` or both at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: I noted there is a difference here: for A1 =  `s,  , , w` (it is `s,␣␣,␣,␣w`. ATTENTION: after the 1st comma, there are two white spaces. but it seems duplicate spaces is replaced with one space here.) 

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^[, ]+|[, ]+$|(, )+","$1")` returns `s , w` (`s␣,␣w`)

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(, )+|(, )+$|(, )+","$3")` returns `s,  , w` (`s,␣␣,␣w`). This is what I need. Just remove any continuously duplicated comma+space (, )

Answer (score 0):

This works, pretending your text is in A1:

```
=join(" ",(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^.*"&rept("(\w,).*",counta(split(regexreplace(A1,"\w,","$"),"$"))-1)&"(\w),?$")))
```

it doesnt quite do it in one formula - like you were asking, I think, but it does handle the various cases.

Comment: The string ", "(a comma + a space) may appear and repeat for more than one time at the beginning or at the end or in one or more positions in the middle. If at beginning or at end it will be removed. If in the middle, only keep one instance at one position.

Comment: The second example  worked when I added additional commas  etc

Comment: Thanks but It seems both don't handle instances at the end.

Comment: @visualPaul fixed, see above